# Unable to install Ubuntu from flash drive on Windows laptop running Windows 7

Tags: boot, flash

Unable to install Ubuntu from flash drive. I have selected USB as first in boot order (there is no secure boot to disable).

Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2330M CPU @ 2.20GHz, 2200 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)
nstalled Physical Memory (RAM) 4.00 GB
Total Physical Memory 3.95 GB
Available Physical Memory 1.97 GB
Total Virtual Memory 7.90 GB
Available Virtual Memory 5.34 GB
Page File Space 3.95 GB

I have tried to install Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS which was not sucessful and I am now trying to install Xubuntu 22.04.4 desktop amd 64iso
I used Rufus to flash the drive with MBR and Target system "BIOS or UEFI"
File System FAT32 (Default) cluster size 16 Kilobytes

on the screen 0.130806] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT)

then /init: line 49: Can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found

Please could someone advise?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Your question is unanswerable. We need more information about your computer hardware such as CPU, RAM, storage. We also need to know which version of Ubuntu you are trying to install. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508666/edit) and add all these in your question above.

Comment: How did you create the USB boot drive?  Please add that to your question as well.  Any more details you can give us can help us help you.

Comment: If an old BIOS only system, better to try a lightweight flavor. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours
Light weight flavors:
Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Budgie
Flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors) While Kubuntu is more of a mid-weight flavor I was able to install on an old BIOS only laptop that would not install Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Comment: `/dev/sr0` indicates that the system tries to boot from a CD/DVD/BD-drive and **not** from a USB-stick.

Comment: I have ranked the boot order so that USB is first. There is a CD/DVD player maybe I'm better off obtaining some CD-R discs and trying to burn to that. I hate having to admit defeat and not be able to flash a USB

Comment: How would I temporarily  disable the CD/DVD drive so the computer can not access it. The internal optical drive is last in the boot order and the external drive is the first in  the boot order

Answer (score -1):

Since you get an error message, it seems to boot.  However perhaps there is something missing or corrupted on the drive.

I would try this :

- download Ubuntu again
- use Rufus to prepare a bootable USB drive (FAT32 worked for me, keep it simple)
- uncompress the Ubuntu .iso on the USB
- try booting on the USB drive and start the installation again

Comment: Thank you for this information I have done as you advised but I still get the same result. the boot order is External device , Network ( which is disabled) , internal hard disc drive

Comment: I have tried this several times with different versions of Ubuntu and different USB sticks and I get the same result